# Piecewise linear approximation for set of points

Tags: algorithms, approximation

If we have a set of points $A$ and a known algorithm $Bestfit(A)$ to find
the best-fit straight line-segment through $A$, what would be a good algorithm to construct piece-wise linear segments (with at most $k$ segments) to give a better approximate of the set of points and reduce the error $E$?

Comment: It depends.  How do you measure "better"?  How do you measure the error $E$?  You'll need a quantitative measure.  Do you have something in mind?  Or would you like us to invent something plausible?

Comment: What is the dimensionality of your points?

Comment: @D.W. : we can suppose than the error $E$ is given as a result of the $Bestfit$ algorithm and we just want to minimize the sum of $E$

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : they are 2-dimensional points

Comment: Sort your points according to their $x$ value. For $k = 2$, you can simply try all possibilities. For larger $k$, and assuming an additive error function, you can use dynamic programming.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  I'm not asking about the error from a straight line; I'm asking how you will measure the error from a proposed set of piecewise-linear segments.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus dynamic programming is a good choice, I will try to use that thank you

Comment: @D.W. simply as the sum of the error for each call of $Bestfit$ (which returns an error $E$ that we don't need to know the mode of calculation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with a straightforward dynamic programming algorithm.  If you have $n$ data points, it can be solved in $O(n^2)$ calls to BestFit plus $O(n^2 k)$ time.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info for our resources on how to construct dynamic programming algorithms.